# Javascript while loop won't function properly

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to do this assignment for my intro to programming class but it won't run properly. What's suppose to happen is that while currTime is less then 50, subtract 5 and display the remaining amount.

```
function display(){
    var currTime = 50;

    while(currTime < 50){
        currTime -= 5;
        document.write("Time remaining: " + currTime + "</br>");
    }

    if(currTime = 25){
        alert("Warning Less than ½ way to launch, time left " + currTime)
    } else if(currTime == 0){
        alert("Blast Off!!! <img src='RocketLaunch.gif' />"); 
    }
}

display();
```

Comment: If `currTime` is 50, `currTime  < 50` is `false`, so the `while` loop will never even start.

Comment: @NickParsons It would, except that `while` is never executed: `50` is never less than fifty. (And if it were, it would be a _very_ long wait for it to stop being less than fifty, as you're _decreasing_ it in the loop.)

Comment: Also, if a number is less than a number and you keep subtracting, it'll stay less than said number

Comment: oh yea, I was just trying it out and I forgot to remove it before posting it. hold on

Comment: `currTime` starts at `50`, and `50 < 50` is `false`

Comment: It won't go inside the loop because current time is not less than 50. It is equal to 50.

Comment: 1, In Your while 50 is equal with 50 and not lower.
2, `currTime = 25` => You will make the variable equal to 25, it not a compare.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is what you want it to do, there were a couple of issues, as you can see from the comments.

```js
function display(){
  var currTime = 50;

  // This should probably run as long as `currTime` is greater than `0`.
  while(currTime > 0) { 
    currTime -= 5;
    console.log("Time remaining: " + currTime + "</br>");

    // Move this `if` inside the while.
    if(currTime == 25){ // replace `=` with `==` for an equality check
        console.log("Warning Less than ½ way to launch, time left " + currTime)
    } else if(currTime == 0){
        console.log("Blast Off!!! <img src='RocketLaunch.gif' />"); 
    }    
  }
}

display();
```

I replaced the `document.write` and `alert` calls with `console.log` as that's more user-friendly when debugging this...

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition in while loop. Don't return the document.write and create the function display. Move the if statements inside the loop

```js
var currTime = 50;

function display() {
  while (currTime <= 50 && currTime >= 5) {
    currTime -= 5;
    document.write("Time remaining: " + currTime + "</br>");
    if (currTime == 25)
      console.log("Warning Less than ½ way to launch, time left " + currTime)
    else if (currTime == 0)
      console.log("Blast Off!!! <img src='RocketLaunch.gif' />");
  }

}
display();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your first while statement as its causing an false value
     while(currTime < 50) make it reverse  while(currTime > 50) and It will start working.

Answer (score -1):

1. The loop won' t start
2. even if you put currTime = 49 or less, the loop won't end. You have to specify something to end the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `currTime < 50` try `currTime <= 50` because `50<50` is False

Comment: Then the OP will have an infinite loop.